# Flex Mobile Project vs. Action script Mobile Project

Tags: actionscript, adobe, flash-builder, flex-mobile

I am new to development and would like to develop an android application. I have previously built an application with Adobe Flash Builder 4.6 with Flex Mobile Project. I just recently noticed in 4.7 there is an option for Action Script Mobile Project.

Can someone please explain to me the difference between the two and the pros and cons to utilizing either or?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pros:
Creating a Flex mobile project is easier (use Flex 4.6 with design mode to rapidly prototype, 4.7 to develop) and visually let's you drag and drop
You can use data binding and other convieniant built in tools

Like anything else, there's good and bad about using the Flex mobile project as oppose to a complete ActionScript based solution. Mainly, it's a lot easier to customize your preloadeder, your splash screen and other features similar to tht like customizing how your application handles screen. Below is a couple pros and cons of using the Flex mobile version instead of ActionScript.

Cons:
Slower performance
Can't use Adobe Scout, it's an awesome tool for real time benchmarking and profiling. Using the built in one is ok but it doesn't give you theamazing information that Scout provides.

My advice: if you're savvy enough to do everything in ActionScript, then definitely create an ActionScript project, your users will love you for it. Plus, it's not that much harder and it lets you have a myriad of additional control over your components. Also, you don't have to deal with the overhead that comes with data binding ( it generates event listeners, get and set methods and you can create much more efficient ones on your own). There are a number of other things that benefit you by creating an ActionScript version like refactoring and better subversion but those are more of incentives than anything else.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Very detailed and answered my questions exactly.

Answer (score 4):

If you plan on making use of the declarative mark-up, built in UI components, and data binding which the Flex framework provides then you should probably start with a Flex Mobile Project. The downside to this approach is that the additional scaffolding of the Flex framework will incur a slight performance hit and will increase the over-all file size of your project.

On the other hand, if performance is critical and you don't need the declarative markup, built in UI components, or data binding provided by the Flex framework, then you should start with a pure ActionScript mobile project. Really simple applications, games, or applications with highly customised UIs would be examples of projects for which a pure ActionScript approach might be more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, you can use Adobe Scout on Flex apps. [Apache Flex](https://blogs.apache.org/flex/entry/apache_flex_announces_the_release) now supports advanced Telemetry.
You can also add advanced telemetry to any SWF with the [SWF Scout Enabler](http://renaun.com/blog/2012/12/enable-advanced-telemetry-on-flex-or-old-swfs-with-swf-scount-enabler/).